# OpenAI Gym - How to create one-hot observation space?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Aside from [openAI's doc](https://gym.openai.com/docs/#environments), I hadn't been able to find a more detailed documentation.

I need to know the correct way to create:

1. An action space which has `1..n` possible actions. (currently using Discrete action space)
2. An observation space that has `2^n` states - A state for every possible combination of actions that has been taken.
   I would like a one-hot representation of the action vector - 1 for `action was already taken`, 0 for `action still hadn't been taken`

How do I do that with openAI's Gym?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the `gym.Spaces` provided by the `gym` package at the time of writing can be used to mirror a one hot encoding representation.

Luckily for us, we can define our own space by creating a child class of `gym.Spaces`.

I have made such a class, which may be what you need:

```py
import gym
import numpy as np


class OneHotEncoding(gym.Space):
    """
    {0,...,1,...,0}

    Example usage:
    self.observation_space = OneHotEncoding(size=4)
    """
    def __init__(self, size=None):
        assert isinstance(size, int) and size > 0
        self.size = size
        gym.Space.__init__(self, (), np.int64)

    def sample(self):
        one_hot_vector = np.zeros(self.size)
        one_hot_vector[np.random.randint(self.size)] = 1
        return one_hot_vector

    def contains(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
            number_of_zeros = list(x).contains(0)
            number_of_ones = list(x).contains(1)
            return (number_of_zeros == (self.size - 1)) and (number_of_ones == 1)
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return "OneHotEncoding(%d)" % self.size

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.size == other.size
```

You can use it thus:

```py
-> space = OneHotEncoding(size=3)
-> space.sample()
array([0., 1., 0.])
-> space.sample()
array([1., 0., 0.])
-> space.sample()
array([0., 0., 1.])
```

Hope I could help

Comment: Nice one! thanks!
I will accept, as this was what I asked, but I now realize what I really wanted was a multi-one-hot space, meaning, several 1's can exist at the same time. How would you implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The "multi one hot" space you ask for is implemented already

https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/multi_binary.py

```
import gym

# create a MultiBinary Space
# by passing n=10, each sample will contain 10 elements

mb = gym.spaces.MultiBinary(n=10)

mb.sample()

# array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int8)
```

If you wanted to implement your own to ensure that there were no more than some number *x* of positive elements when calling `sample`, you could choose *x* indices randomly from *n* options and then flip those indices in an array of all `0` and then return that.